# Fastlane Match with Gitlab Secure Files - Can't use different private token for code signing repo in CI/CD

Tags: gitlab-ci, fastlane, fastlane-match

We've been having some issues getting Fastlane Match to work in Gitlab CI using access tokens from within an existing CI pipeline.

**The setup:**

1. Repo for storing the certs / profiles: set up during `fastlane init`. We'll call this the "Cert Repo".
2. Repo for our React Native project: uses fastlane to handle builds/uploading to App Center and Testflight. We'll call this the "Project Repo"

Setup of `match` via `match init` went fine. We did the setup via terminal on the build server.

In our Matchfile:

1. gitlab_project("PATH_TO_CERT_REPO_HERE")
2. storage_mode("gitlab_secure_files")
3. app_identifier(["APP_IDENTIFIER_HERE"])
4. username("APPLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE")
5. keychain_password("KEYCHAIN_PW_HERE")
6. team_id("TEAM_ID_HERE")

We had to pass in some env vars to the command for our gitlab enterprise api url (as "CI_API_V4_URL" and the Cert Repo access token as "PRIVATE_TOKEN"

We ran match for all cert/profile types we needed and they all uploaded to the secure files section of the Cert Repo correctly.

**The Problem:**

Our branches in the Project Repo use Gitlab CI to run various scripts and call a fastlane lane that will do the versioning, certs/profiles, and then upload the build to App Center or Testflight.

When we run match in readonly mode in our lane this way, match is failing with a 401 error.

Looking into the source for match and secure files for storage, it seems if you have a `PRIVATE_TOKEN` env var set, match will give a warning that you have both `JOB_TOKEN` and `PRIVATE_TOKEN` set and it will use the `JOB_TOKEN`.

The JOB_TOKEN is provided via Gitlab CI itself.

My guess is the JOB_TOKEN for this pipeline is not a valid token to authenticate against the CERT_REPO, which match needs to download the certs/profiles.

How is this supposed to work if I can't pass in a token for match to use for the CERT_REPO?

If we were using normal git storage, you can pass in the `git_basic_authorization` argument and give the base64 encoded `"username:acces_token"` string, which I'm assuming would solve the problem.

But using `gitlab_secure_files`, you can only use tokens.

Before we go and redo everything to use git storage and not gitlab secure files, can someone explain what we're missing here?

How is match supposed to authenticate with the Cert Repo from within the Project Repo in CI if the token it has is for the Project Repo? Doesn't it need the token for the Cert Repo to authenticate?

Comment: I noticed you're specifying the storage mode as `gitlab_secure_files` but you're pointing it to a different repo? Is that a supported configuration? My understanding is that it would store the cert/profiles in the same repo under the secure files, not in a different repo.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with my gitlab repos but on CircleCI.
Match failed cloning the certificate repo with the error:

> Error cloning certificates repo, please make sure you have read access
> to the repository you want to use ...

Setup:

1. Repo for the certificates
2. Repo for the iOS app.

Match file:

```
git_url("git@gitlab.com:PATH_TO_GITLAB_REPO.git")
storage_mode("git")

type("development") # The default type, can be: appstore, adhoc, enterprise or development

username("INSERT YOUR VALUE") # Your Apple Developer Portal username

app_identifier([
    "first identifier",
    "second identifier",
    "third identifier"
])
```

The solution was adding the DeployKey of the second Repo (of the iOS App) to the first Repo (of the certificates repo).